# Divide a circular photo into four parts with hover

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a problem with exercise.
I made a circle that has several hovers.
I want to put a picture in the background of this 4-part circle (attached code) and when it has hovered, this picture should be divided into 4 pieces and have a puzzle shape.
I won't run with HTML and CSS.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cULPj.jpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: medium;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Parent {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top: 40%;
  background-color: darkorchid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.piece {
  background-color: darksalmon;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(img/fire.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

#pie-1 {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  background-position: left top;
}

#pie-2 {
  top: 0%;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  left: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  background-position: right top;
}

#pie-3 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
}

#pie-4 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  background-color: darkviolet;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
}

.Parent:hover #pie-1 {
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.Parent:hover #pie-2 {
  transform: translate(100%, -100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.Parent:hover #pie-3 {
  transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.Parent:hover #pie-4 {
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="Parent">
  <Div class="piece" id="pie-1"></Div>
  <Div class="piece" id="pie-2"></Div>
  <Div class="piece" id="pie-3"></Div>
  <Div class="piece" id="pie-4"></Div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made an example working in javascript https://jsbin.com/xixayiy/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will consider the code from [an article that I have written](https://css-challenges.com/css-image-splitting/) doing the same effect:

```css
.image {
  --s: 40px; /* the offset */
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/YYlTEtw.jpg);
  background-size: 0 0;
}

.image > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: center/cover no-repeat;
  background-image: inherit;
  -webkit-mask: conic-gradient(from var(--d, 0deg), #fff 0 calc(360deg/4), transparent calc(360deg/4 + 1deg) 360deg);
  mask: conic-gradient(from var(--d, 0deg), #fff 0 calc(360deg/4), transparent calc(360deg/4 + 1deg) 360deg);
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
}

.image > *:nth-child(1) { --d: calc(1 * (360deg/4));}
.image > *:nth-child(2) { --d: calc(2 * (360deg/4));}
.image > *:nth-child(3) { --d: calc(3 * (360deg/4));}
.image > *:nth-child(4) { --d: calc(4 * (360deg/4));}

.image:hover > *:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(var(--s), var(--s));
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var(--s)), var(--s));
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var(--s)), calc(-1*var(--s)));
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(var(--s), calc(-1*var(--s)));
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Another version with clip-path more supported that mask and conic gradient:

```css
.image {
  --s: 40px; /* the offset */
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/YYlTEtw.jpg);
  background-size: 0 0;
}

.image>* {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: center/cover no-repeat;
  background-image: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
}

.image :nth-child(1) {
   clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(var(--s),var(--s));
}

.image :nth-child(2) {
   clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var(--s)), var(--s));
}

.image :nth-child(3) {
    clip-path:polygon(0 0,50% 0,50% 50%,0 50%);
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var(--s)),calc(-1*var(--s)));
}

.image :nth-child(4) {
   clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 50%);
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(var(--s), calc(-1*var(--s)));
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

And without clip-path, using only background properties:

```css
.image {
  --s: 40px; /* the offset */
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/YYlTEtw.jpg);
  background-size: 0 0;
}

.image > * {
  position: absolute;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background: center/200% 200% no-repeat;
  background-image: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
}

.image :nth-child(1) {
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background-position:bottom right;
  border-radius:0 0 50% 0;
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(var(--s),var(--s));
}

.image :nth-child(2) {
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-position:bottom left;
  border-radius:0 0 0 50%;
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var(--s)), var(--s));
}

.image :nth-child(3) {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-position:top left;
  border-radius:50% 0 0 0;
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(calc(-1*var(--s)),calc(-1*var(--s)));
}

.image :nth-child(4) {
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-position:top right;
  border-radius:0 50% 0 0;
}

.image:hover>*:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(var(--s), calc(-1*var(--s)));
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right and you want to divide ONE picture in four parts - it's impossible without javascript. And even then it would be quit difficult...

What you can do, you can divide this picture in four parts with some photo editior and then put each part as a background of a corresponding div element.

Or, if you want to achieve this in your manner, each of your .piece should have the same background-size property (better set it in pixels to the parent div) and then your background-positioning could possibly work (I would rather propose the exact positioning in px than "top left" etc.).

As for the "puzzle form", you could try to use pseudo-elements ::before and ::after to add some shapes above the pictures. Or you could use the nested divs instead.

Also read about blobs, maybe it could inspire you:
https://css-tricks.com/blobs/

Answer (score 1):

I'm made a very basic working example in javascript, I hope you find it useful.

```
<!--http://jsbin.com/xixayiy/16/edit)-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<style id="jsbin-css">
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: medium;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Parent {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top: 40%;
  background-color: darkorchid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.piece {
  background-color: darksalmon;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#pie-1 {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
}

#pie-2 {
  top: 0%;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  left: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
}

#pie-3 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
}

#pie-4 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  background-color: darkviolet;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045);
  /* easeInBack */
}

.Parent:hover #pie-1 {
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.Parent:hover #pie-2 {
  transform: translate(100%, -100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.Parent:hover #pie-3 {
  transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.Parent:hover #pie-4 {
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="Parent">
  <Div class="piece" id="pie-1"></Div>
  <Div class="piece" id="pie-2"></Div>
  <Div class="piece" id="pie-3"></Div>
  <Div class="piece" id="pie-4"></Div>
</div>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">

const img = new Image();
const pie_1 = document.getElementById('pie-1');
const pie_2 = document.getElementById('pie-2');
const pie_3 = document.getElementById('pie-3');
const pie_4 = document.getElementById('pie-4');

var background_image = "https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/binaries/content/gallery/metofficegovuk/hero-images/advice/maps-satellite-images/satellite-image-of-globe.jpg";
// var background_image = "https://cdn.jpegmini.com/user/images/slider_puffin_before_mobile.jpg";

img.src = background_image;

img.onload = function() {

  var position = {
    Y:-this.height/2 + pie_1.offsetHeight,
    X:-this.width/2 + pie_1.offsetWidth,
    height:pie_1.offsetHeight,
    change:0,
  }
  
  initalise_background()

  function calculate_position() {
    position.change = pie_1.offsetHeight - position.height;
    position.Y+=position.change;
    position.X+=position.change;
    undate_position()
    position.height = pie_1.offsetHeight;
  }
  
  function initalise_background() {
    set_background(background_image, pie_1)
    set_background(background_image, pie_2)
    set_background(background_image, pie_3)
    set_background(background_image, pie_4)
  }
  
  function undate_position() {
    set_position(position.X, position.Y, pie_1)
    set_position((position.X - pie_1.offsetWidth), position.Y, pie_2)
    set_position(position.X, (position.Y - pie_1.offsetHeight), pie_3)
    set_position((position.X- pie_2.offsetHeight), (position.Y - pie_1.offsetHeight), pie_4)
  }
  
  function set_background(image, element) {
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + image + ")";
  }
  
  function set_position(x, y, element) {
    element.style.backgroundPosition = x + "px " + y + "px";
  }
  
  window.onresize = event => {
    calculate_position()
  }

  window.onload = event => {
    undate_position()
  }
  
}
</script>
```